# python requests with redirection

Tags: python, authentication, redirect, curl, python-requests

Trying to authenticate on http://72.ru site, noticed that there were a redirect to https://loginka.ru/auth/. Found that there were 302 POST with plain credentials in data form. Copying headers from Chrome can reproduce that in cURL, but still can't reach in requests module.

Warning: page is full of russian letters, registration in the box north-east

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.auth = ('EMAIL', 'PASSWD')

    s.post('http://72.ru/passport/login.php')
    p = s.get('http://72.ru/job/favorite/vacancy/')

    # will print True if logged
    print('some title from favorite page, if logged' in p.text)
```

Why can't authenticate, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much simpler way to perform login to this website.

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36",
}

s = requests.session()
s.headers.update(headers)

# There is a dedicated login page, which is the url of the Login button on the site, you can open that directly. 
# Requests will automatically take care of rediects
s.get('https://loginka.ru/auth/?url=http%3A%2F%2F72.ru')

# Generate the post data
data = {
    'url': 'http://72.ru',
    'email': username,
    'password': password
}

# Perform the post request
r = s.post('https://loginka.ru/auth/?url=http%3A%2F%2F72.ru', data=data)

# There is an extra post request on this site which uses token from redirect url
token = r.url[r.url.index('token=')+6:]
url = 'http://72.ru/put_token_to_user/?token=' + token + '&dummy_put_token_to_user=yes'
headers2 = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Referer': r.url}
r = s.get(url, headers=headers2)

r = s.get('http://72.ru/passport/mypage.php')
print r.url
print r.status_code
with open('abc.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 9):

I think you need to specify `allow_redirects=True`

```
s.post('http://72.ru/passport/login.php', allow_redirects=True)
```

Comment: There is no such attribute. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=session#requests.Session.post

Comment: **kwargs optional arguments that are passed to the underlying requests.request call

Comment: Still no changes even with allow_redirects=True =(

Comment: Bro it has now helped me somewhere, where server was probably redirecting to create hidden server variables. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
from calendar import timegm
from time import gmtime

import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36",
}

s = requests.session()
s.headers.update(headers)
epoch1 = '%s000' % timegm(gmtime())
s.get('http://72.ru/')
epoch2 = '%s000' % timegm(gmtime())
login_url = 'https://loginka.ru/service/api/passport/auth/token/?callback=jQuery17107978048569057137_%s&_=%s' % (epoch1, epoch2)
s.get(login_url)
epoch3 = '%s000' % timegm(gmtime())
params = {
    'callback': 'jQuery17107978048569057137_%s' % epoch1,
    'email': username,     # Username Email
    'password': password,     # Password
    'remember': 0,
    '_': epoch3
}
r = self.s.get('https://loginka.ru/service/api/passport/auth/login/', params=params)
print r.content
```

Comment: Nice, but jQuery callback changes each time, can't find how to determain behavior, each epoch1 in login_url are different either. So still can't get {'auth':'true'} response.

Comment: I just edited the code. Using 3 epoch's now. Apart from that I think that the big number after jquery should not be a problem, you can use a static one as I have provided.

Comment: but how determine number of ?callback=jQuery[NUMBER] ?

Comment: That is what I mentioned, that try to use any static number over there and hopefully it should work, you can use the one from my code. I dont have valid credentials to the site so I cant test that.

Comment: I tried a lot of times, and each time there was different number. Ok, thanks, I'll try more.

Comment: I agree that each time there is a different number but its just my feeling that that number should not affect. Epoch could be the reason. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80602/discussion-between-vikas-neha-ojha-and-kaldown).